# Syntax Error at Database Connection String asp.net & c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have written code to connect to insert asp.net form data into an SQL server, created in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, using c#. The issue I am having now is that I am unable to test if form works due to a Synax error. There are spaces between the text file, I am not sure if that might be the reason why there is an error? Or misplaced connection file? I copied the pathing directly from Microsoft Access. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> > Line 11: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
> >
> > Line 12: {
> >
> > Line 13:     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data
> >     Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:
> >     \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio
> >     2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf";Integrated
> >     Security=True");
> >
> > Line 14:     protected void Page_Load(object sender,
> >     EventArgs e)
> >
> > Line 15:     {
> >
> > Source File: C:\Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio
> >     2015\WebSites\WebSite2\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 13

This is the form code in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table values('" + pName.Text + "','" + pEmail.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf\";Integrated Security=True")
```

Because it isnt clear for the compiler what you mean. So we use "\" as a signal that the following char should be interpreted as... well a char - and not as a keyword.

Otherwise " is interpreted as start/end of a string which results in 
string one: *"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"*

"unlogical" data (because not start or end sign): C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf\

and string two: *;Integrated Security=True*

Other possibility:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + @"C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf" + ";Integrated Security=True")
```

Anyways using a web.config/app.config is way better for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. When I update the string to the first recommendation you have I get the same error, and when I update it to the second string I get a similar error: "Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected"

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

Answer (score 0):

You're using `"` two times in the same string I don't think they'll work even prepending `@`. Try using `\"` also a connection string should be in the `app.config` or `web.config` file. Never **hardcoded** in your source.

Answer (score 0):

Use connection strings and the web.config for easing changes.

web.config example:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="LoginDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\P\\Docs\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Change your code to:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LoginDB"].ConnectionString);
```